# Can I use EMACS for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, linux, emacs

I would like to use EMACS, can I use this editor to develop javascript application?

Thank you

Comment: I think what dail means is whether there is good *JS support* for Emacs. Of course any text editor can be used for programming in any language.

Comment: The question needs to be re-phrased, then. As it stands, the question is pretty ludicrous given that a web search for "emacs javascript" will turn up ample evidence in the affirmative.

Answer (score 3):

[js2-mode](http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/) is a good major mode to start for your javascript development, try it.

Comment: js2-mode along with [mozrepl](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MozRepl) to integrate with your running browser (firefox)'s javascript environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any text editor to write javascript. It's all interpreted by the browser (or by something like the v8 engine if you're doing Nodejs), so there's nothing but text.

Comment: There's a lot more to using a language aware editor than "just text". Smart indentation, syntax highlighting, completions etc. The choice of an editor can affect ones programming productivity significantly.

Comment: @Noufal what editor do you prefer for javascript?

Comment: Those are nice features, but they're not required, and they don't answer his question, which was whether he can use EMACS. All you need to write javascript is any text editor, because it's not compiled. Now whether he'd like things like syntax highlighting or whatever is another question.

Comment: user156629: The comment by Thomas to the original question is accurate I think.